# Capturar una palabra entre dos strings con expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA</ns2:sApellido1>
<ns2:sApellido2>SILVA</ns2:sApellido2>
```

Estoy tratando de capturar lo que se encuentra entre `<ns2:sApellido1>` y `</ns2:sApellido1>` Mediante expresiones regulares.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
/<(ns2:sApellido1)>.*<\/(ns2:sApellido1)>/g
```

Pero me toma toda la línea, estoy tratando y leyendo sobre expresiones, pero no he podido. Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Lectura recomendada cada vez que pienses en parsear XML con expresiones regulares: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345  Ahora bien, por qué capturas los tags si lo que necesitas es el contenido? `<ns2:sApellido1>(.*)<\/ns2:sApellido1>`

Comment: O también prueba con `/<ns2:sApellido1>(.*?)<\/ns2:sApellido1>/`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev al probarla sigue tomando toda la línea :S

Comment: Estás usando javascript?

Comment: pues la verdad estoy consumiendo un servicio que esta en SOAP y me devuelve un XML, debo recorrerlo y sacar la información que está entre esas etiquetas mediante una función o una expresión regular, no puedo usar librearías solo Js pelado jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar esta expresión regular para encontrar todo el texto que están entre esas etiquetas:

```
/<ns2:sApellido1>(.*?)<\/ns2:sApellido1>/
```

Hacemos la prueba en JavaScript:

```js
let regex = /<ns2:sApellido1>(.*?)<\/ns2:sApellido1>/;
let texto = '<ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA</ns2:sApellido1>';
console.log(regex.exec(texto)[1]);
```

Y si son varios textos, tendrías que recorrerlo y usar `matchAll()` para encontrar todas las coincidencias del regex en tu cadena (por eso se usa la bandera `/g` en el regex para buscar en la cadena de inicio a fin):

```js
let regex = /<ns2:sApellido1>(.*?)<\/ns2:sApellido1>/g;
let texto = `
  <ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA1</ns2:sApellido1>
  <ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA2</ns2:sApellido1>
  <ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA3</ns2:sApellido1>
  <ns2:sApellido1>GARCIA4</ns2:sApellido1>
`;

let iterador = texto.matchAll(regex);

for (let resultado of iterador) {
  console.log(resultado[1]);
}
```

Comment: ERES EL MEJOR jajaja te amo <3 mil gracias funcionó :D :D

Comment: Un gusto ayudarle, saludos!